# Spresense VSCode 使用時のmake時間について

Tags: spresense

[Spresense SDK スタートガイド (IDE 版)](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html) に従って、VSCodeでコマンドのビルドを実施しましたが、２回目以降のビルドも40分ほどかかってしまいます。
毎回SDKも含む `make all` を実施しているため時間がかかっているように見えるのですが、こちら差分makeにする方法はありますでしょうか？
※スタートガイドの例にそうと、myapps_main.cを変更した際にこれだけビルドするようにして時間を短縮したい

OS:Windows10
メモリ:8GB

[image: SDKコンフィグ画面]

Comment: プロジェクトに含まれる Makefile の内容を質問に文字のまま貼り付けておくと、回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは。

修正したファイルのみをビルドした差分ビルドとは違うのですが、 WSL2 を使うという方法でビルド時間を短縮こともできると思います。

最近のSpresense SDKやSpresenseVSCodeIDEの更新でWSL2用の対応が入ったようで、この環境に切り替えると格段にビルド時間が短縮されるようです。(参考:[Spresense開発環境のビルド時間を比較してみた](https://qiita.com/baggio/items/efc78d8b3862b5890c9f))

私もWSL2環境に切り替えたところビルドが1分ほどでできて快適にアプリを作れるようになりました。(公式ではWindows11でサポートと書いてありましたが、私のWindows10でも問題なく動きました。)

takahashi さんもWSL2に切り替えてみると解決するかもしれません。